# How to avoid EOFException for an empty HTTP response from HttpURLConnection?

Tags: java, http, exception, inputstream, httpurlconnection

I'm sending an HTTP request to a server which legitimately returns a blank response with HTTP response code = 200 (OK).

But this causes the marked line below to throw an `EOFException`:

```
InputStream responseStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
final String contentEncoding = this.connection.getContentEncoding();
if ("gzip".equalsIgnoreCase(contentEncoding)) {
    responseStream = new GZIPInputStream(responseStream); // throws EOFException
}
```

There may be an obvious way to prevent this but I can't find it. Should I perhaps be checking something like `connection.getContentLength() > 0` or `responseStream.available() > 0` before creating the GZIPInputStream? Neither of these seem quite right and I haven't come across anything similar in example code fragments...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Should I perhaps be checking something like connection.getContentLength() > 0

Yes.

> or responseStream.available() > 0

Definitely not. available() == 0 isn't a valid test for EOF, and the Javadoc explicitly says so.

Comment: Many thanks - looks like getContentLength() it is then. Only slight concern is I don't want to introduce a check that might rule out valid responses - do you know if content-length is always guaranteed to be set properly by the server?

Comment: @SteveChambers Content-length is perhaps the most important header of all in HTTP 1.1. If it isn't set properly, the server is badly broken, and browsers won't work with it either.

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't your server return HTTP code 204 (No Content), instead of 200? Except for a HEAD request that is. See [Http Status Code definition](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html)

Apart from that, you could indeed just check to work around what looks like a not-all-too-compliant server implementation, or catch the exception and then determine the proper action depending on the type of request you sent.

Comment: Interesting point and I agree a 204 would have been better - but I have no control over this and think the 200 with blank response is valid - albeit perhaps not "standard". I'd prefer to avoid an exception happening in the first place if at all possible - this goes against my programming instincts e.g. I like to debug in Eclipse and catch any type of Exception as a breakpoint - this should usually indicate an error rather than unusual data.

Answer (score 1):

What I understand from your question is that this exception is being thrown consistently everytime you get a `200` response from the server.

If `responseStream.available() > 0` is not an option, it means that the stream actually contains something, but that stream seems to be incomplete or ending prematurely by any other means, since `available` states that there ARE readable bytes in the stream.

---

*Update*

Based on your comment (and after reading `InputStream`'s doc again out of sheer curiosity) I also believe `connection.getContentLength() > 0` is the way to go. If you're using Java 7, tough, `connection.getContentLengthLong()` is preferred over that because it returns a `long` directly.

Given what the docs say about [`InputStream#available`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available%28%29) :

> The available method for class InputStream always returns 0.

And

> Note that while some implementations of InputStream will return the total number of bytes in the stream, many will not. It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream.

This discards that check as an option.

Comment: I don't always get the exception - there are plenty of responses from the server with 200-OK that do contain data but this particular one doesn't. The actual use case is an ACK sent to the server as part of an asynchronous data flow. The server replies with 200 (OK) in reply but doesn't have anything more to say (i.e. the response is blank).

Comment: @SteveChambers So my assumption was wrong, my apologies about that. I also believe `connection.getContentLength` (or `connectionlgetContentLengthLong` if possible) is the option.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful. I'm seeing good results with connection.getContentLength().

Answer (score 0):

Unless I'm missing something, a response with Content-Encoding "gzip" by definition can not be empty.

Comment: Not sure if you're intending to expand this but at present it seems more of a comment than an answer - perhaps provide a reference as to why it can't be empty (am assuming this would be somewhere in the HTTP spec?) Anyway sometimes what a spec says and what can actually be done differ - the question describes what was seen and it seems others may have seen something similar e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22831793) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40251180).

Comment: If the server says "content-encoding: gzip" then the payload MUST be gzipped; an empty payload by definition isn't gzipped. Thus the HTTP response is invalid.

Comment: That does sound logical but IIRC the question was about a response received that was out of my control and still needed to be handled appropriately. Guess the word "legitimately" in the first sentence may be wrong.