# How to read a textual HTTP response into a String exactly as-is?

Tags: java, bufferedreader, readline, eof, carriage-return

The following code uses BufferedReader to read from an HTTP response stream:

```
final StringBuilder responseBuilder = new StringBuilder();
String line = bufferedReader.readLine();
while (line != null) {
    responseBuilder.append(line);
    responseBuilder.append('\n');
    line = bufferedReader.readLine();
}
response = responseBuilder.toString();
```

But appending `'\n'` to each line seems a bit flawed. I want to return the HTTP response exactly as-is so what if it doesn't have a return character after the last line? One would get added anyway using the code above - is there a better way?

Comment: I believe you are getting html "text"? is that right? are you adding `\n` because you want it in a "human" readable form? because any parser should handle the response even without linebreaks

Comment: Yes, the content type is `text/xml`. For the purposes of what the system does it doesn't really need to be human readable but it is being logged to a log file so would need to be for that reason.

Comment: well, then I'd recommend runnign it through a "pretty print" library (also taking care of ident). I think http://sourceforge.net/projects/jtidy/ would be pretty. Just smash the whole response into it and request pretty print output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I want to return the HTTP response exactly as-is

Don't use `readLine()` then - it's as simple as that. I'd suggest using a `StringWriter` instead:

```
StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
char[] buffer = new char[8192];
int charsRead;
while ((charsRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    writer.write(buffer, 0, charsRead);
}
response = writer.toString();
```

Note that even this won't work if you get the encoding wrong. To preserve the *exact* HTTP response, you'd need to read (and write) it as a *binary* stream.

Comment: To preserve the exact HTTP response you need to read the bytes, without mediating a `Reader`, and you also need to be aware of the Content-Length issue.

Comment: @EJP - I did come across a Content-Length issue, raised in an earlier q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14817310/java-how-to-prevent-eofexception-for-an-empty-http-response Is this the same issue you are referring to?

Comment: @EJP: Agreed on the binary side of things - see the end of my answer. For the content length, I'd *expect* the reader to already do the right thing.

Comment: What reader? If the input is coming from an HttpURLConnection it all happens for you, but if it's a socket it doesn't: you have to stop reading at the Content-length if there is one, handle chunked encoding, etc, yourself; otherwise you can overrun the body and start reading the next request. There's no evidence here of which it is.