# gzip compression results in empty response on bad request, works fine otherwise

Tags: angularjs, spring, apache, http, gzip

I am doing a HTTP POST request from a web client using angular with the following header:

```
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
```

The server response content-type is application/json. When the response status is 200, everything works fine, my response has a body that I can see from the client. However, when the response status is 400, the response body is empty according to the client, but I am certain I am populating it on the server. Also, if I remove "gzip" from the request header above (no change server-side whatsoever), then everything works fine even with a 400 response status, in other words I can see the response body from the client. I'm running Tomcat with Spring on the server side.

It really seems like gzip is the cause of my problem here, but I don't understand why or how to fix it, any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We figured it out, we were using an old version of the ehcache-web library and thus its GZipFilter, which didn't return the response body for any status other than 200. Upgrading to version 2.0.4 of that library fixed the issue.